# Is it a good practice to parse JSON into an interface instance in angular?

Tags: json, typescript, angular

When receiving the response from the server, should I parse the JSON into an interface instance?
I'm using typescript, so type safety seems something to pursue.
Can you point to an example?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that is that if you use `JSON.parse()`, the object you get won't have any instance methods. 
It's only a piece of data. 
It doesn't matter if you cast it to something else.

Comment: But at least you know which fields it contains and make it harder to misspell then.

Comment: Yes, you'll definitely gain some type safety and it can definitely be used well. However just be careful with this!